# Second Order Differential Equation

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

$\ddot{x}+\frac{2\sqrt{15}}{3}\dot{x}+\frac{5}{3}x=0$, general form $e^{-wt}(At+B)$

Comment: Are you asking or telling ? The question is not clear.

Comment: Sorry, how do you solve it?

Comment: Please edit the question and also include your thoughts on the question.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The idea is that you try to show us some effort, so you can pinpoint where exactly you are struggling and we know how best to help you. So, can you add to your post where exactly you are getting stuck? And what you have tried?

Comment: Thank you. Am I on the right lines writing $3r^2 +2\sqrt{15}r+5=0$?

Comment: @KyleJohnson Yes, that is a good start! Now, try evaluating the roots of the quadratic.

Answer (score 2):

You have a linear diff eq with constant coefficients.

The characteristic equation is $\lambda^2 +\frac {2\sqrt 15}{3} \lambda + \frac 53 = 0$

find the roots of the characteristic equation.

There are three possibilities:

you have two real roots.

You have two complex roots.

You have one real root of multiplicity 2.

What have you got?  What is the solution when the characteristic equation has that form?

Comment: [+1] good framework for somebody who hopefuly, has no idea of the method to use.

Comment: So, if the solutions are both real rational numbers, do I have to use the general formula $c_{1}e^{r_{1}x}+c_{2}e^{r_{2}x}$?

Comment: Indeed you would.  Do you have two real numbers as your roots?